# define an array of input control in aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an input control of type file.

```
<input id="FileUpload1" type="file" runat="server" size="35" />
```

there are four input controls like this and in aspx.cs file i m trying to make an array of these ids..

i have made an array

```
HtmlInputFile[] fl = new HtmlInputFile[4] { FileUpload1, FileUpload2, FileUpload3, FileUpload4 };
```

but it gives me an error..how can i get the value of these inputs.

Comment: What kind of error? Compiler error? Exception?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? I mean why do you need this array ? Do you need an ID array ? or control array ? and what exception do you get ?

Comment: when i try to get the filename through
string filename = fl[i].PostedFile.FileName;
it says object reference not set to an instance

Answer (score 1):

The

```
FileUploadX.PostedFile
```

Property is null if no file was uploaded. You need to check wether

```
FileUploadX.HasFile == true
```

before attempting to access it.

In case you are using ASP.Net AJAX updatepanels, you'll run into all sorts of proplems with FileUpload. See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100706212558/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mmintoff/archive/2009/04/01/fileupload-within-updatepanel.aspx) for possible solutions